# Where did the mockery of Jesus take place?

Tags: life-of-jesus, crucifixion

Before he was crucified, Jesus was mocked by the soldiers and by members of the Sanhedrin.   Where did this mockery take place?

Comment: Welcome! Is there a particular reason that the location matters to you that we could also help you with?

Comment: Well, I'm studying for an exam about the gospels, and I'm trying to make sure I have the details right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The soldiers mocked Him in the hall called the Praetorium (Matthew 15:16). The Jewish leaders spit on Him in the palace of the High Priest (Matthew 14:65) and also at the cross (Matthew 15:31).